# TeamCity API - Determine which build step(s) caused the failure

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I'm working on metrics collection, and it would be very useful to know how many builds failed due to tests, compilation, etc. I can collect the status from the build object in the API, but I can't figure out how to determine which step (or steps) failed.

Anyone know how to get this from the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you cannot. But you might configure several build configurations and set up [dependencies](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Dependencies) between them - this approach provides you with some statistics and [statistics charts](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Statistic+Charts), both project- and build configuration-level.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this approach simply isn't feasible. Breaking each build up such that each step is it's own build configuration.... I'll have to open a ticket with TeamCity support - this seems like an oversight.